# Why are Raspberry Pi's vi key bindings so quirky?

Tags: raspbian

Have you ever noticed that the default `vi` key bindings on the `Raspberry Pi` are a little wacky? For example, while in insert mode, try using the arrow keys to navigate. Not happening :)

Is this a subtle way of getting us to use insert and command mode properly or maybe the bindings were just overlooked when the image was built?

I'm quite used to a certain key mapping in Fedora/Debian that allows the use of navigation keys while in insert mode. To get the familiar bindings I'm used to, do I need to fiddle with terminal emulation or some sort of configuration file somewhere?

Comment: I expect it's because you are used to `vim` and what you're now experiencing is truly `vi`. On modern distros, the `vi` command is often syslinked to `vim`.

Comment: Is this through ssh? You might need to even try `stty sane` and setting your TERM variable (`export TERM=linux` is usually easiest for me to remember)

Comment: Which version? Latest (oct release) seems OK, at least over ssh.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The default package is `vim-tiny`. You can install a version that is more familiar:

`sudo apt-get install vim`

Extra configuration and customization can be placed in the `.vimrc` file in your home directory.

Comment: Thanks buddy! Just when I thought there was no more hope, you saved the day :)

Answer (score 2):

Remove and purge vim-tiny before installing vim. It will work as expected after that.

Comment: Had to do this as well. vim-tiny and vim seem to depend on different versions of vim-common and that prevents me from installing both.

Answer (score 1):

I also had this problem when I logged in as the root user but not the pi user. I have also installed vim with:

```
apt-get install vim
```

That didn't solve it alone but a little digging and I discovered that it was some environment variable differences. I managed to get my happy vi behavior of being able to move around with the cursor keys even in insert mode by simply changing the /root/.profile file to read as follows:

```
if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
  if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
    . "$HOME/.bashrc"
  fi
fi

if [ -d "$HOME/bin" ] ; then
  PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
fi
```